# React-native unable to compile and run

Tags: android, react-native

Created a basic App through WebStorm from the built-in template. It has the problem both with Android while iOS works fine, here's the stack trace.

I've installed Android studio and have an emulator running as I'm compiling the react-native program. I've the react-native cli installed as well, not sure what I'm missing.

> errorCould not compile settings file
>   '/Users/john/Documents/Scratches/ReactTest/android/settings.gradle'.
>
> > startup failed:Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up:    General error during
> >     semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version
> >     57https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment

Another error down the stack trace.

> - What went wrong: Could not compile settings file '/Users/john/Documents/Scratches/ReactTest/android/settings.gradle'.
>
>   > startup failed:   General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 57
>   >      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 57

here's my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check your build.gradle under android folder and verify the sdkversion.  May be the targetsdkversion could be an issue. Just a hunch.

Comment: posted my build.gradle

Comment: I suppose you have already gone through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58345916/android-launch-issues-unsupported-class-file-major-version-57

Comment: I see, any idea on when gradle will upgrade to support it, instead of downgrading jdk, how come Android studio (a new blank project) is able to compile it fine?